# WinForms - UserControl - List<bool> an Collection<bool> as Browseable Property of UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, propertygrid, design-time

Why the MessageBox and CheckBox apprears in Design-Time when changing value of the First property and do not when adding item to Second?

```
    private string _first;
    [Description(""), Category("GostcompSettings"), DefaultValue("27017")]
    public string First
    {
        get { return __first; }
        set
        {

            _searchAreasChceckBoxList.Clear();
            pPanelWithCheckboxies.Controls.Clear();
            int x = 10;
            int y = 10;

            CheckBox _tempCheck = new CheckBox();
            _tempCheck.Checked = true;
            _tempCheck.Location = new Point(x, y);

            _searchAreasChceckBoxList.Add(_tempCheck);
            pPanelWithCheckboxies.Controls.Add(_tempCheck);

            MessageBox.Show("zmiana");
            _first = value;
        }
    }


    private Collection<bool> _second= new Collection<bool>();
    [Description(""), Category("*")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public Collection<bool> Second
    {
        get
        {
            return _second;
        }
        set
        {

            _searchAreasChceckBoxList.Clear();
            pPanelWithCheckboxies.Controls.Clear();
            int x = 10;
            int y = 10;

            CheckBox _tempCheck = new CheckBox();
            _tempCheck.Checked = true;
            _tempCheck.Location = new Point(x, y);

            _searchAreasChceckBoxList.Add(_tempCheck);
            pPanelWithCheckboxies.Controls.Add(_tempCheck);

            MessageBox.Show("*");
            _second= value;
        }
    }
```

It's the same scenario when I change Collection to List...
Values are kept (or added to Collection in Second case) and designer generate code for InitializeComponent().

EDIT after @taffer answear

```
public class SearchAreaInfo
{
    public SearchAreasEnum searchArea
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

public class SearchAreaInfoCollection : Collection<SearchAreaInfo>
{
    private Panel _checkboxParent;

    public SearchAreaInfoCollection(Panel checkboxParent) : base()
    {
        _checkboxParent = checkboxParent;
    }

    // called on Add/Insert
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, SearchAreaInfo item)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
        RepaintChackboxPanel();
    }

    // called on Remove/RemoveAt
    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        base.RemoveItem(index);
        RepaintChackboxPanel();
    }

    // called when an element is set by the indexer
    protected override void SetItem(int index, SearchAreaInfo item)
    {
        base.SetItem(index, item);
        RepaintChackboxPanel();
    }

    private void RepaintChackboxPanel()
    {
        //_searchAreasChceckBoxList.Clear();
        _checkboxParent.Controls.Clear();
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        foreach (var item in this)
        {
            CheckBox _tempCheck = new CheckBox();
            _tempCheck.Checked = true;
            _tempCheck.Location = new Point(x, y);
            _tempCheck.BringToFront();

            //_searchAreasChceckBoxList.Add(_tempCheck);
            _checkboxParent.Controls.Add(_tempCheck);                
            x += 5;
            y += 5;
        }
        _checkboxParent.Invalidate();
    }
}

    private SearchAreaInfoCollection _searchAreas;
    [Description(""), Category("GostcompSettings")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public SearchAreaInfoCollection SearchAreas
    {
        get
        {
            return _searchAreas;
        }
    }
```

Now the prooblem is that: when I add let's say third item to the collection in Editor it draws only one checkbox but should draw 3 checkboxes...
Moreover in debugging I see that foreach loop goes then 3 times: 1st collection has 1 item , 2nd time collection has 2 items and third time collection has 3 items, but finally I see just one checkbox in _checkboxPanel.

Answer (score 1):

Because the setter of `Second` property is executed only when you replace the whole collection. When you add/remove an item, the getter returns your collection instance (`_second`), and the `Add`/`Remove` method will be called on that object instance.

If you want to perform checks on element addition/removal, create a custom collection type instead:

```
public class MyBoolCollection: Collection<bool>
{
    // called on Add/Insert
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, bool item)
    {
        // do some checks here
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }

    // called on Remove/RemoveAt
    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        // do some checks here
        base.RemoveItem(index, item);
    }

    // called when an element is set by the indexer
    protected override void SetItem(int index, bool item)
    {
        // do some checks here
        base.SetItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is also some inconvinience. When I click `Add` button in `Collection Editor` it always calls `InsertItem`. When click Remove it calls `RemoveItem` only on OK when exiting from `Collection Editor`.

Comment: To the comment before. I noticed that most of the people override just Add and Clean methods. So I think it works like this that when we remove one item it clears whole collection and then adding N-1 items again...

Answer (score 1):

The built-in collection editor that you are using now only changes the *content* of your collection object.  Which works fine, but does not get your setter called at all.  In other words, it never creates a new collection object, nor does it know how to do that.

To get your property setter called, you have to create your own UITypeEditor and have it return a new collection from its EditValue() method override.  Pretty easy to do, first add a reference to System.Design, then make your code look similar to this:

```
using System.Drawing.Design;
...
        [Editor(typeof(MyEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
        public Collection<bool> Second {
            // etc...
        }

        private class MyEditor : UITypeEditor {
            public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context) {
                return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
            }
            public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value) {
                var editor = new System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor(typeof(Collection<bool>));
                var retval = (Collection<bool>)editor.EditValue(context, provider, value);
                return new Collection<bool>(retval);

            }
        }
```

You probably want to improve this a bit, like implementing your own editor UI so all of those bools are easier to interpret.